# Lower bandwith of jpegs

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to lower the size of images I am loading from a database and urls. I am making them smaller

```
$('#table-body').prepend($('<img>', {
  id: 'theImg',
  src: "the_image_url.jpeg",
  height: 20,
  width: 20
}));
```

[Images sizes too high....height:20,width:20](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jsnw6.png)

Comment: Can you clarify your problem, or at least share a question?

Comment: I want to lower the amount of bandwith I am grabbing to get those files. I  want to load way less than 4mb for a 20x20 thumbnail

Comment: All you're doing is making the displayed image smaller. You're not affecting the bandwidth of the image at all. If you want to do that you'll need to process the image server-side to re-sample it.

Comment: theres no in between from my webpage? they have to have a large medium and small to some extent?

Comment: I found this so I am just going to do some reading, thank you for the server-side resizing suggestion!!

Comment: The height and width in the `<img>` tag only controls how the image is rendered. It does nothing about the file size of the image. As has been commented already, you need to start off with smaller images on the server.

Comment: @peeebeee I am reading up on base64 image encoding. I don't think any of these images have been base64 decoded and my teacher only spoke for a second about how bandwidth can base saved with it.

Comment: You probably just need to resample the jpgs to the size that you need to display them at. Your server-side technology might be able to do that on the fly, or you can run them through some software that does the job - choice of that is outside the scope here I suspect, but Google will help.